# UICollectionView, dynamic layout according to count of datasource array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I have several sections, each sections' datasource may contain a number of items ranging from 1 to 6. Each cell is a known size.

Whilst maintaining centred alignment I would like to be able to 'push' items 5 & 6 onto the next row if they exist.

I've been grappling with a custom layout but just can't get this effect.

Might autolayout be able to help achieve this?

Thanks in advance